rsync performance issues on large directories
I'm trying to clone a directory tree with millions of files from a remote server to my local machine with rsync and running into some issues.
rsync on Mac OS creates an extra ._ file for every single file. Since these are all approx 4k and many of the files are very small this is increasing the space requirement by something like 50% so 200GB is now consuming 300GB. Additionally, since every file now requires two writes, it seems to be going much slower than the same action performed on a linux box.
At the moment the process has been running for approx 8 hours and will take at least another 30. Based on my bandwidth and network speed, this should only take 2 at the most.
I know there have been serveral related questions on the topic:

Why are dot underscore ._ files created, and how can I avoid them?
Disable storage of invisible files "._" on my cfs or smb network storage

My question is concerned specifically with how to get "normal" performance out of rsync in this situation, or if not possible, how to clone a remote directory tree efficiently without all the extra overhead of creating millions of 4k .- files.

@Seamus - what bearing does that have on my question?
